# Corrupted USB Media

Tags: usb-drive, corruption

Hi Guys I have two identical USB Drives that behave identically wrong...

After copying a bunch of files I unmounted them and it after 15mins of waiting for the write cache (while the cpu load is at zero oddly enough) I gave up and just removed the drive.

Now they are not usable at all. I would have expected that some files are not there (because not written) but not the following behaviour:

`lsusb` output before either one of the drives is installed

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc. Logilink CR0012
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:6082 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and now after (note that it took about 5 seconds to until there was any difference in the lsusb output so i had to run the command a couple of times (why actually?))

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc. Logilink CR0012
Bus 001 Device 008: ID ffff:1201  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:6082 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Device with ID 24ae:1100 is a card reader that I know so ffff:1201 must be the pen drive.
`lsscsi -s` output before inserting the medium:

```
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  ASUS     DRW-24D5MT       1.10  /dev/sr0        -
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST1000DM003-1SB1 CC43  /dev/sda   1.00TB
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      INTENSO SATA III 61.3  /dev/sdb    240GB
[6:0:0:0]    disk    Intenso  USB 3.0 Device   0     /dev/sdc    500GB
[7:0:0:0]    disk    Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0903  /dev/sdd        -
```

and after:

```
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  ASUS     DRW-24D5MT       1.10  /dev/sr0        -
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST1000DM003-1SB1 CC43  /dev/sda   1.00TB
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      INTENSO SATA III 61.3  /dev/sdb    240GB
[6:0:0:0]    disk    Intenso  USB 3.0 Device   0     /dev/sdc    500GB
[7:0:0:0]    disk    Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0903  /dev/sdd        -
[8:0:0:0]    disk    NAND     USB2DISK         0.00  /dev/sde        -
```

obviously it's detecting the pendrive and just can not determine it's size.

The end of the syslog file is :

```
Oct 15 17:17:01 DESKTOP CRON[6093]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3055.640984] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3055.797273] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3055.797278] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3055.797692] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3055.798138] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3"
Oct 15 17:22:13 DESKTOP mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Oct 15 17:22:14 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
Oct 15 17:22:14 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3
Oct 15 17:22:14 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3056.813556] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Oct 15 17:22:14 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3056.814000] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
Oct 15 17:22:14 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3056.816168] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
Oct 15 17:25:28 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3250.754042] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 8
Oct 15 17:25:29 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
Oct 15 17:25:29 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3297.441199] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3297.597388] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3297.597393] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3297.597842] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3297.600635] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3"
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
Oct 15 17:26:15 DESKTOP upowerd[1603]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3
Oct 15 17:26:16 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3298.622108] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Oct 15 17:26:16 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3298.622653] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
Oct 15 17:26:16 DESKTOP kernel: [ 3298.625530] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
Oct 15 17:27:34 DESKTOP gvfsd-metadata[1771]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

at one point it says that the device was removed then it got reconnected (of course because I did so quite some number of times by now) and it does not show it to be disconnected again.

GParted does not show the drive (because they are of undeterminable size i guess). Windows 7 and Windows 10 do show it in `diskmgmt.msc` but also no size available (they both believe there is no medium inserted (like with a Card reader which it definitely is not). Testdisk does not show the device.
Manually mounting the device is also not possible for reasons...

A try to zero the whole device with `dd` failed because:

```
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde count=32G
[sudo] Passwort für marc: 
dd: konnte '/dev/sde' nicht öffnen: Kein Medium gefunden
marc@DESKTOP:~$
```

(Note that the Drive is supposed to have 32GB so that the count-argument is actually meaningful)

Using the knowledge of the underlying SCSI Device makes me do the following:

```
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg5 count=32G
dd: Schreiben in '/dev/sg5': Das numerische Argument ist außerhalb des Definitionsbereiches
2+0 Datensätze ein
1+0 Datensätze aus
512 Bytes kopiert, 0,000349558 s, 1,5 MB/s
marc@DESKTOP:~$
```

So there is at least something happening although the count argument being out of range i think is very irritating (I tried it everything greater than 1 is out of range...)

And the `dmesg` output end with

```
[ 1837.253976] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1837.254176] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 1838.277632] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     General  USB Flash Disk   1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1838.278571] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 1838.279953] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] 7831552 512-byte logical blocks: (4.01 GB/3.73 GiB)
[ 1838.281670] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[ 1838.281675] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1838.283098] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
[ 1838.283105] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1838.288217]  sde: sde1
[ 1838.292686] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1889.632142] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 3055.640984] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 3055.797273] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 3055.797278] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 3055.797692] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3055.798138] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 3056.813556] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 3056.814000] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 3056.816168] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3250.754042] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 3297.441199] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 3297.597388] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 3297.597393] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 3297.597842] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3297.600635] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 3298.622108] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 3298.622653] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 3298.625530] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
marc@DESKTOP:~$
```

fsck leads to:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sde
fsck von util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Kein Medium gefunden beim Versuch, /dev/sde zu öffnen

Der Superblock ist unlesbar bzw. beschreibt kein gültiges ext2/ext3/ext4-
Dateisystem. Wenn das Gerät gültig ist und ein ext2/ext3/ext4-
Dateisystem (kein swap oder ufs usw.) enthält, dann ist der Superblock
beschädigt, und Sie könnten versuchen, e2fsck mit einem anderen Superblock
zu starten:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <Gerät>
 oder
    e2fsck -b 32768 <Gerät>
```

And e2fsck does the same...

*TLDR* I have about 64GB worth of USB Storage on my desk that both fail for the same reason and that are both not usable with the same sympthoms.
Any ideas?! Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:
I just figured that I potentially use sg_dd to zero the whole thing but nope:

```
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo sg_dd if=/dev/sg5 count=67108864
Assume default 'bs' (block size) of 512 bytes
Device (r) not ready
sg_read failed, at or after lba=0 [0x0]
Some error occurred,  remaining block count=67108864
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
1 unrecovered error(s)
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo sg_dd if=/dev/sg5 count=67108864
Assume default 'bs' (block size) of 512 bytes
Device (r) not ready
sg_read failed, at or after lba=0 [0x0]
Some error occurred,  remaining block count=67108864
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
1 unrecovered error(s)
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo sg_dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg5 count=67108864
Assume default 'bs' (block size) of 512 bytes
device not ready (w)
sg_write failed, seek=0
Some error occurred,  remaining block count=67108864
128+0 records in
0+0 records out
1 unrecovered error(s)
marc@DESKTOP:~$ sudo sg_dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sg5 bs=128 count=67108864
device not ready (w)
sg_write failed, seek=0
Some error occurred,  remaining block count=67108864
128+0 records in
0+0 records out
1 unrecovered error(s)
marc@DESKTOP:~$
```

Note that 32G/512 is the 67108864 blocks specified (32*1024*1024*1024/512)

Comment: Anecdotal comment: I have a USB thumbdrive which did the very same. The device turned out to be of poor quality. Upon writing on it the first time, the flash memory got hot and melted. The controller could not make heads and tails of the damaged flash memory and presented itself as 0 bytes capacity storage medium. Maybe something like that happened to you twice.

Comment: Side note: dd uses blocks of 512 byte per default. So `dd count=32G` tries to write 16384 GiB of data. You want `dd count=64M`.

Comment: mmm that byte size thing explains something but the drives didnt get hot at all. and they are from a reputable source so i dont guess that its that. also no burnt electronics small anywhere...

Comment: Same thing happened here except with a 500GB Pen (Thumb) Drive.
Tried everything both you fellows did, no joy.
Don't recall any odd smells, and believe me I've let enough smoke escape components to know that scent... Paid 30 usd for the thumb, so don't really want to trash it. Did either of you ever figure out a way to re-establish a file system on the media ? Would have made this a comment, but the 50 points prerequisite is a bit steep.

Comment: nope the only thing that i could think of that could potentially work is dismanteling the thing and going in with a soldering iron thin wire and a jtag programmer or something along those lines.